# don't want to show facebook profile image

Tags: asp.net, facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-javascript-sdk

when I am using this code, it is showing logged in Facebook user profile image on my "default.aspx" page which I don't want. All I wanted is that allowing the user to login, redirecting to my app and then accessing the public profile information. Is there any way to suppress profile image here.

```
 <html>
 <head><title>FaceBook Login</title></head>
 <body>
 <div>Welcome</div>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
        // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
        if (response.status === 'connected') {               
            testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {               
            FB.login();
        } else {               
            FB.login();
        }
    });
};

 // Load the SDK asynchronously
 (function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 } (document));

 function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        //var str = JSON.stringify(response) + " ";
        //console.log(str);
        //alert(str.toSource());
        alert(response.id);
        //console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
 }
  </script>
  <fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: And also can I customize the facebook login button or use my own custom login button??

Comment: Is there any way to hide login button and directly opening the facebook login dialog using java script when the user is not logged in to the facebook ?